# Want to set variable either true or false based on Status column values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to set variable either true or false based on Status column values, if any value is coming Cancel in Status column then I want to set variable as false OR want to set as true.

I have query like this :

```
Select Status from tablename where Id = 77 and ThreadId IN (30, 40, 50, 60, 69, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400)
```

So now this query is returning all status for this company for this all threads. It is returning values either Cancel OR Accept.

```
Accept
Accept
Accept
Accept
Cancel
Accept
Accept
```

What I want to do is, if any value is Cancel coming then I want to set variable as false in this query so is it possible ?

Comment: You can loop through your return result from the query and set the variable there.

Comment: Couldnt you add where logic to say if status = Cancel for any of them then set variable to false, if no results are returned, then you know none of them are cancel and can set it to true.

Comment: select @variable = max(case when Status = 'Cancel' then 1 else 0 end) as cancelled from yourtable...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to declare some variable with default value true/false, then execute below query using **ExecuteScalar()**. This return result as single int value which you need to store in another variable named for example **count**.

```
select 
    COUNT(Status) AS Status
from tablename 
where Id = 77 and ThreadId IN (30, 40, 50, 60) and Status = 'Cancel'
```

Now, you can use result of above query for further process

```
if(count > 0)
{
    Status = false;
}
```

**OR**

```
DECLARE @Count int;
DECLARE @Status NVARCHAR(5);

SET @Count = (select 
    COUNT(Status) AS Status
from tablename 
where Id = 77 and ThreadId IN (30, 40, 50, 60) and Status = 'Cancel');

IF(@Count > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'false'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'true'
END
```

In above query value of **@Status** variable is exactly return what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can use case statement :

```
select CASE WHEN Status='Accept' THEN 'True'
               ELSE 'False' END AS status_boolean
from tablename where Id = 77 and ThreadId IN (30, 40, 50, 60, 69, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use sql case expression

```
Select case when Status='Cancel' then 'false' end as Status from tablename where Id = 77 and ThreadId IN (30, 40, 50, 60, 69, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select case when max(Status) = 'Accept' then 'true' else 'false' end as flag
from tablename 
where Id = 77 and 
  ThreadId IN (30, 40, 50) -- list other ids
```

When there is no 'Cancel' value then all the status values would be 'Accecpt', the max function will return 'Accept', and the case expression evaluates to true.